# Compare the decimal points in ios

Tags: macos, decimal

There is a problem to compare the system version in Mac OS.
I'm current working on 10.8.4 mountain lion and i needs to compare with whether Mac OS is 10.9 and above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare them as strings using `NSNumericSearch`.

```
[@"10.8.4" compare:@"10.9" options:NSNumericSearch];
```

The return value from this method is `NSComparisonResult`.  If left argument is smaller than the right argument, the constant `NSOrderedAscending` is returned.  If the right argument is smaller, the constant `NSOrderedDescending` is returned.  If they are equal, the constant `NSOrderedSame` is returned.

---

```
if ([@"10.8.4" compare:@"10.9" options:NSNumericSearch] < NSOrderedAscending) {
    // 10.8.4 is smaller than 10.9
}

if ([@"10.10" compare:@"10.9" options:NSNumericSearch] < NSOrderedDescending) {
    // 10.10 is larger than 10.9
}
```

The `NSNumericSearch` options don't particularly matter for the first comparison, but they do make a difference in the second comparison.  Without `NSNumericSearch`, the strings would be compared character by character, and 1 < 9, so it'd claim 10.10 is < 10.9.

Comment: its only compares that whether it is 10.8.4,but i need that its greater than 10.9 or not.

Comment: Then compare whatever value you have to 10.9 using NSNumericSearch as options

Comment: Can you explain please how to compare greater than or not? i tired but i didn't get it. need to check this 10.8.4<10.9 how??